# Google Cloud Platform: VPC Connector Not Working with Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, vpn

We're developing a web server with Firebase that will have to talk to various PLCs behind customer firewalls. I have a couple PLCs on my local network that I'm working with. I'm just trying to do a basic ping right now. I installed the ping module and am trying to run this node.js code:

```js
function pingTest(){ 
 const ping = require('ping'); 
 const hosts = [
  '10.10.100.11',
  '10.10.100.119',
  '10.10.100.12',
  '10.10.100.118',
 ];
 hosts.forEach(function(host){
  ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive){
   var msg = isAlive ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive' : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
   console.log(msg);
  });
 });
}
```

I've setup a VPN gateway and tunnel on GCP. The tunnel status is "Established". I have a Serverless VPC Access Connector setup as well. Everything is using the "us-central1" region. The connector is assigned to my cloud function for all traffic.

Running locally, I can ping the .11 and .12 PLCs just fine. When running in Firebase though, all four hosts report "dead".

When looking at the GCP Logs Viewer, I'm not seeing any error codes. The logs for my function are only what I'm writing to the console:

- 10:06:00.180 AM every1MinuteBackgroundPlcRead Function execution started
- 10:06:02.693 AM every1MinuteBackgroundPlcRead host 10.10.100.11 is dead
- 10:06:03.793 AM every1MinuteBackgroundPlcRead host 10.10.100.12 is dead
- 10:06:03.794 AM every1MinuteBackgroundPlcRead host 10.10.100.119 is dead
- 10:06:04.393 AM every1MinuteBackgroundPlcRead host 10.10.100.118 is dead
- 10:07:00.206 AM every1MinuteBackgroundPlcRead Function execution took 306 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

I'm not even seeing an option for VPC connector logging. I see the option for the tunnel logs; but there're empty. The logs for the gateway are just these lines repeated over and over:

- 2020-02-24T15:00:27.885866755Z sending DPD request
- 2020-02-24T15:00:27.886004404Z generating INFORMATIONAL request 95 [ ]
- 2020-02-24T15:00:27.886142741Z sending packet: from 34.66.113.10[500] to 50.205.87.130[500] (49 bytes)
- 2020-02-24T15:00:27.911746950Z received packet: from 50.205.87.130[500] to 34.66.113.10[500] (49 bytes)
- 2020-02-24T15:00:27.911828853Z parsed INFORMATIONAL response 95 [ ]

It doesn't seem like my code is utilizing the VPC connector that I assigned to the function. I assume I'm missing a critical link in my chain? Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to create a VM in your project and to perform the ping from this VM? I already set up some VPN, and, most of time, my error was that I always forgot of the route back. Check on the VM before looking at the serverless VPC access

Comment: I didn't know I could set up a VM! I'll look into it.

Comment: I have a "Microsoft, Windows Server, 2019 Datacenter, Server with Desktop Experience" VM setup. I can't remote into it with either Remote Desktop or Chrome RDP; which is just one more point of frustration. I can get into it with a command window though. I can't ping my PLCs in the VM either. I'm researching to see if I have to do extra steps to connect my VM to my VPN now.

Comment: I use only Linux VM. I'm sorry, I can't help you on this! The aim is to perform a ping from another point into the VPC that is not a Functions. VM is the best solution for this!

Comment: Damn. Well, thanks for helping to point me in a different direction.

Comment: I spun up an Ubuntu VM. That was a lot easier than a Windows one! Although, I still can't ping internal IP's through the VPN.

Comment: Start by solving this network issue and then go back to the Cloud Function. As mentioned before, the route back is often missing (in my case I always forget it!)

Comment: I was finally able to remote into the VMs. After that, we determined that the switch the PLCs were on wasn't working like it was supposed to. So, we moved them to a different switch. Long story short: I can finally ping the PLCs from the VMs. (yay!) But I still can't ping them from my function. (boo!) I'm wondering if it has something to do with the "IP Range" I have to specify when creating a connector. These "must be correct" but I don't know what is correct. I was specifying "10.10.0.0/28" to get the whole range my PLCs are on. I tried "10.10.100.0/28" as well.

Comment: I've also tried "10.10.199.0/28".